# SQLite INNER JOIN WHERE column not null

Tags: ios, sqlite, inner-join

I'm trying to get this SQL query correct but I keep getting a single row with null values.

So I got two tables.

Table A is `chat` table.

Table B is `wallpaper` table.

`chat` may or **may not** have any wallpaper ID assigned to is foreign key.

I'm trying to get the wallpaper attached to a chat using the following query:

```
const char *query = "SELECT wallpaper.* FROM wallpaper INNER JOIN chat ON wallpaper.id_wallpaper = chat.id_wallpaper AND (chat.id_chat = ? AND chat.id_wallpaper NOT NULL)";
```

inside my method:

```
-(Wallpaper *)getWallpaperForChatHeaderID:(NSString *)chatHeaderID
{
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    const char *query = "SELECT wallpaper.* FROM wallpaper INNER JOIN chat ON wallpaper.id_wallpaper = chat.id_wallpaper AND (chat.id_chat = ? AND chat.id_wallpaper NOT NULL)";

    Wallpaper *wallpaper = nil;

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, query, -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 1, [chatHeaderID intValue]);

        int statusCode = sqlite3_step(statement);

        if(statusCode == SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            long idWallpaper = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);

            char *dbFilename = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);

            ...

            wallpaper = [[Wallpaper alloc] initWithWallpaperID:idWallpaper ....];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"sql step status error code: %d", statusCode);
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to get wallpaper for chat header with ID: %@", chatHeaderID);
    }

    return wallpaper;
}
```

But that keeps returning me a single `wallpaper` entity with all fields NULL.

A chat can only have 1 wallpaper. So I only want to fetch a single `wallpaper` where it is linked to a chat based identified by the chatHeaderID.

As far as I can see, the SQL query found the matching `chat` entry from the `chat` table based on the `chatHeaderID` I passed in but it seems to be ignoring my WHERE clause:

```
(chat.id_chat = ? AND chat.id_wallpaper NOT NULL)
```

What I was expecting to see is the SQL query returning 0 entries at the moment because I have not linked any wallpaper entries with any chat entries.

Any ideas ? :D

Comment: Actually you're missing the WHERE clause:

`const char *query = "SELECT wallpaper.* FROM wallpaper INNER JOIN chat ON wallpaper.id_wallpaper = chat.id_wallpaper WHERE chat.id_chat = ? AND chat.id_wallpaper NOT NULL";`

Comment: I though when you put the round brackets around (chat.id_chat = ? AND chat.id_wallpaper NOT NULL) it means WHERE ? Sorry my SQL knowledge isn't very far.

Comment: I've tested both, seems to work  :P

Comment: Why are you using an *inner* join?

Comment: I read something about LEFT OUTER JOIN doesn't eliminate NULL rows or something when there is a match (http://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/joins.php), I didn't want the SQL to return me rows containing NULL data as was evident in my above code so I used INNER JOIN and hoped it would fix my filter problem, . Is LEFT OUTER JOIN better performance than LEFT INNER JOIN ?

Answer (score 0):

Another one of my question solved by myself =/

Not sure why the above question code doesn't work but I've found a work around which seems to give the expected outcome.

```
-(Wallpaper *)getWallpaperForChatHeaderID:(NSString *)chatHeaderID
{
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    const char *query = "SELECT wallpaper.* FROM wallpaper INNER JOIN chat ON wallpaper.id_wallpaper = chat.id_wallpaper WHERE chat.id_chat = ? AND chat.id_wallpaper NOT NULL";

    Wallpaper *wallpaper = nil;

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, query, -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 1, [chatHeaderID intValue]);

        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            long idWallpaper = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);

            ...

            wallpaper = [[Wallpaper alloc] initWithWallpaperID:idWallpaper ...];
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to get wallpaper for chat header with ID: %@", chatHeaderID);
    }

    return wallpaper;
}
```

The difference here is I'm using:

```
while(... == SQLITE_ROW) 
{ 
    ... 
}
```

condition to check for matching rows that also satisfy the WHERE filter conditions :)

I want to point out that I've changed the above SQL query to using:

```
SELECT wallpaper.* FROM wallpaper INNER JOIN chat ON wallpaper.id_wallpaper = chat.id_wallpaper WHERE chat.id_chat = ? AND chat.id_wallpaper NOT NULL
```

but I have tested:

```
SELECT wallpaper.* FROM wallpaper INNER JOIN chat ON wallpaper.id_wallpaper = chat.id_wallpaper AND (chat.id_chat = ? AND chat.id_wallpaper NOT NULL)
```

and both seems to work.

I'll use the one that includes the explicit `WHERE` keyword as it looks more readable.